# Make Email Regex Comma Delimited

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex, razor

I have the following regular expression to validate a single email address. How do I make this regex accept a comma delimited list of email addresses?

```
^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

I am placing the regex within an input tag using a razor view:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="Email field exceeds maximum length of 50" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-regex="Email-Address is invalid" data-val-regex-pattern="^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Why don't you split your string on the comma, and then test each mail adress individually?

Comment: Why your regex contain spaces?

Comment: Avinash - I think that space is just the line break when inputting it on this page. Fixed it.

Comment: Deblaton - I am trying to maintain the same workflow as the single email address validation.

Comment: Don't restrict TLDs to `{2,6}$` many exceed 6 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just have interior optional comma separated list, its usually done like
`(?:my regex)(?:,my regex)*`

```
 #  ^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+[_.+-]+)*[A-Za-z0-9]+@(?:\w+[.-]+)*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?:,(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+[_.+-]+)*[A-Za-z0-9]+@(?:\w+[.-]+)*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})*$

 ^ 
 (?: [A-Za-z0-9]+ [_.+-]+ )*
 [A-Za-z0-9]+ 
 @
 (?: \w+ [.-]+ )*
 \w{1,63} \. [a-zA-Z]{2,6} 
 (?:
      ,
      (?: [A-Za-z0-9]+ [_.+-]+ )*
      [A-Za-z0-9]+ 
      @
      (?: \w+ [.-]+ )*
      \w{1,63} \. [a-zA-Z]{2,6} 
 )*
 $
```